# Debian : configure an send-only smtp server (exim or postfix)

Tags: debian, email-server, exim

I’m configuring a debian server and I need a mail server for all notifications (fail2ban, logwatch, etc). I need those notification to be send to a specific email address. I have an smtp account with my domain I can use.

I successfully configured exim to use this smtp server by using the "**satellite**" mode here is my `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='satellite'
dc_other_hostnames=''
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost='mydomain.com'
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='mysmtp-server:587'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

This works great for **outgoing** mail but when I send a mail to @localhost the mail is sent to my smtp server and is lost.

I want exim to store the mail to @localhost in Maildir in home of my local users.

I can also use postfix if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want smarthost rather than satellite configuration. Satellite is for sending all mail another host and no local mail (except specified in /etc/aliases). Smarthost is send all non-local mail to another-host.

Just change:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='localhost;myhost.mydomain'
```